# matplotlib quiver() displaying double arrows

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

The code below is producing double arrows. This is most noticeable in the center and along the bottom row.

Am I missing something or is this a bug of some sort? The Googlebox has yielded nothing helpful.

```
X = [[ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]]

Y = [[ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
         1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
         1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
         2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,
         3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,
         4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4],
       [ 5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,
         5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5],
       [ 6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,
         6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6],
       [ 7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,
         7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7],
       [ 8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,
         8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8],
       [ 9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,
         9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9],
       [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,
        10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,
        11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11],
       [12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
        12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12],
       [12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
        12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12],
       [13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13,
        13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13],
       [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14,
        14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
       [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15,
        15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15],
       [16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16,
        16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16],
       [17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17,
        17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17],
       [18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18,
        18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18],
       [19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19,
        19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19],
       [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20,
        20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
       [21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21,
        21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21],
       [22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22,
        22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22],
       [23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23,
        23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23]]

U = [[ 5.91106782e-01,  6.22366562e-01,  6.49723913e-01,
         6.58423221e-01,  6.34788082e-01,  5.64001424e-01,
         4.29552877e-01,  2.26181450e-01, -1.45749370e-02,
        -2.33836090e-01, -3.97062982e-01, -5.07288787e-01,
        -5.80344621e-01, -6.28652118e-01, -6.56798746e-01,
        -6.59563028e-01, -6.18178096e-01, -5.00722193e-01,
        -2.93582966e-01, -5.16521582e-02,  1.45799368e-01,
         2.69658133e-01,  3.26500153e-01,  3.26768709e-01],
       [ 5.77152607e-01,  5.82746773e-01,  5.76183972e-01,
         5.43266956e-01,  4.66312191e-01,  3.24661378e-01,
         1.07385088e-01, -1.54908642e-01, -3.91341641e-01,
        -5.56849441e-01, -6.55288824e-01, -7.07393105e-01,
        -7.30393353e-01, -7.34785105e-01, -7.24202206e-01,
        -6.92703347e-01, -6.16664334e-01, -4.51489078e-01,
        -1.96144234e-01,  3.89095593e-02,  1.80222779e-01,
         2.38107484e-01,  2.33390450e-01,  1.75753839e-01],
       [ 5.55201554e-01,  5.36916267e-01,  4.95331092e-01,
         4.14297782e-01,  2.72441471e-01,  5.30267270e-02,
        -2.23958353e-01, -4.85686407e-01, -6.72063827e-01,
        -7.80930667e-01, -8.34052999e-01, -8.49154520e-01,
        -8.36753045e-01, -8.02912499e-01, -7.48984464e-01,
        -6.66861836e-01, -5.28032125e-01, -2.83307017e-01,
         2.22999217e-02,  2.17035214e-01,  2.78107345e-01,
         2.57213982e-01,  1.80414526e-01,  5.58040480e-02],
       [ 5.30514869e-01,  4.88045325e-01,  4.08507605e-01,
         2.73305715e-01,  6.32261747e-02, -2.15499555e-01,
        -5.00468423e-01, -7.16424820e-01, -8.46362641e-01,
        -9.11763344e-01, -9.32463829e-01, -9.17913774e-01,
        -8.71699781e-01, -7.94959450e-01, -6.84618047e-01,
        -5.27977847e-01, -3.00601184e-01,  3.24725025e-03,
         2.84572480e-01,  4.15678719e-01,  4.08817699e-01,
         3.17903989e-01,  1.68926905e-01, -2.47734503e-02],
       [ 5.02548139e-01,  4.33179379e-01,  3.10308116e-01,
         1.15832201e-01, -1.53873192e-01, -4.53740654e-01,
        -7.02597717e-01, -8.60992569e-01, -9.43881451e-01,
        -9.75369646e-01, -9.68057700e-01, -9.24950942e-01,
        -8.45413757e-01, -7.27664488e-01, -5.66705523e-01,
        -3.53336189e-01, -8.54415234e-02,  2.02537484e-01,
         4.30399404e-01,  5.35069052e-01,  5.14397103e-01,
         3.91608994e-01,  1.87450108e-01, -6.90256334e-02],
       [ 4.65201575e-01,  3.63695264e-01,  1.90407737e-01,
        -6.27986111e-02, -3.66107539e-01, -6.43527995e-01,
        -8.36008710e-01, -9.43058071e-01, -9.89396085e-01,
        -9.93329532e-01, -9.61559805e-01, -8.93929627e-01,
        -7.88224158e-01, -6.41454775e-01, -4.49066265e-01,
        -2.09439702e-01,  6.10838713e-02,  3.17493844e-01,
         5.06540308e-01,  5.97919655e-01,  5.83094325e-01,
         4.57218933e-01,  2.21129548e-01, -8.56001665e-02],
       [ 4.07605489e-01,  2.67483222e-01,  4.05687053e-02,
        -2.54052862e-01, -5.49121397e-01, -7.74824152e-01,
        -9.12683654e-01, -9.80602627e-01, -9.99708951e-01,
        -9.81982007e-01, -9.30930539e-01, -8.45440583e-01,
        -7.22549396e-01, -5.57873670e-01, -3.47081454e-01,
        -9.50528305e-02,  1.70316784e-01,  4.02869279e-01,
         5.66564552e-01,  6.47406192e-01,  6.37165072e-01,
         5.16241932e-01,  2.63738110e-01, -8.10456144e-02],
       [ 3.16982526e-01,  1.36224084e-01, -1.31317283e-01,
        -4.28869103e-01, -6.80165940e-01, -8.50494619e-01,
        -9.46930042e-01, -9.87780174e-01, -9.87413002e-01,
        -9.53497923e-01, -8.88237499e-01, -7.90275139e-01,
        -6.55616984e-01, -4.77864944e-01, -2.52458286e-01,
         9.81222811e-03,  2.71633461e-01,  4.87237886e-01,
         6.32706314e-01,  7.04459838e-01,  6.96319353e-01,
         5.81475147e-01,  3.21122831e-01, -5.36729232e-02],
       [ 1.89851174e-01, -1.85511352e-02, -2.92612142e-01,
        -5.56206782e-01, -7.55569048e-01, -8.83561174e-01,
        -9.52641527e-01, -9.75602026e-01, -9.61454612e-01,
        -9.15325308e-01, -8.38796591e-01, -7.30116952e-01,
        -5.83859882e-01, -3.91508312e-01, -1.49024508e-01,
         1.25224816e-01,  3.84250312e-01,  5.84434393e-01,
         7.13492616e-01,  7.76382012e-01,  7.69585148e-01,
         6.63495229e-01,  4.05530281e-01,  8.00655892e-03],
       [ 4.93393011e-02, -1.59077638e-01, -4.07446556e-01,
        -6.27159359e-01, -7.86840781e-01, -8.87988595e-01,
        -9.40149757e-01, -9.51231448e-01, -9.26802697e-01,
        -8.70250066e-01, -7.82391229e-01, -6.60618012e-01,
        -4.97916636e-01, -2.84557428e-01, -2.01313492e-02,
         2.65144709e-01,  5.15478531e-01,  6.95092413e-01,
         8.05054050e-01,  8.57357453e-01,  8.51220724e-01,
         7.58939184e-01,  5.22126402e-01,  1.20841224e-01],
       [-6.08161695e-02, -2.48600589e-01, -4.63433277e-01,
        -6.50364713e-01, -7.86735731e-01, -8.73048406e-01,
        -9.15192518e-01, -9.18037801e-01, -8.84901395e-01,
        -8.17468539e-01, -7.15217876e-01, -5.74265632e-01,
        -3.86590763e-01, -1.44298331e-01,  1.42640838e-01,
         4.27841719e-01,  6.54596037e-01,  8.04151106e-01,
         8.90457558e-01,  9.29136623e-01,  9.21288722e-01,
         8.45538031e-01,  6.51467861e-01,  2.89354206e-01],
       [-1.11855856e-01, -2.76262916e-01, -4.66494984e-01,
        -6.36195917e-01, -7.62707033e-01, -8.42791922e-01,
        -8.79618811e-01, -8.76344309e-01, -8.34510258e-01,
        -7.53704299e-01, -6.31437753e-01, -4.62760383e-01,
        -2.41283252e-01,  3.19831190e-02,  3.28392442e-01,
         5.90402526e-01,  7.76991386e-01,  8.90488023e-01,
         9.51679598e-01,  9.75365138e-01,  9.63233139e-01,
         9.01562554e-01,  7.57051594e-01,  4.78793525e-01],
       [-1.02763752e-01, -2.49208456e-01, -4.25698141e-01,
        -5.90445663e-01, -7.17037110e-01, -7.97411218e-01,
        -8.32440059e-01, -8.24121526e-01, -7.72259450e-01,
        -6.73888301e-01, -5.24476588e-01, -3.20200623e-01,
        -6.29603397e-02,  2.27897175e-01,  5.06403936e-01,
         7.23466314e-01,  8.64328407e-01,  9.44675955e-01,
         9.84485357e-01,  9.95247332e-01,  9.78583745e-01,
         9.26839981e-01,  8.22017325e-01,  6.32198023e-01],
       [-4.76297792e-02, -1.80235400e-01, -3.48835361e-01,
        -5.15498990e-01, -6.48860867e-01, -7.34607790e-01,
        -7.70573611e-01, -7.57371172e-01, -6.92888223e-01,
        -5.71674412e-01, -3.88941513e-01, -1.47948226e-01,
         1.31928638e-01,  4.12166625e-01,  6.47847253e-01,
         8.14343231e-01,  9.16397002e-01,  9.71963635e-01,
         9.96490008e-01,  9.98129614e-01,  9.78410399e-01,
         9.33624383e-01,  8.55392368e-01,  7.29066548e-01],
       [ 3.44453327e-02, -8.45500183e-02, -2.44567678e-01,
        -4.13390951e-01, -5.55986626e-01, -6.50278759e-01,
        -6.88905719e-01, -6.69887784e-01, -5.89049719e-01,
        -4.40034407e-01, -2.23153205e-01,  4.24368019e-02,
         3.17706147e-01,  5.60575371e-01,  7.45372080e-01,
         8.69074149e-01,  9.43218293e-01,  9.82237250e-01,
         9.96859104e-01,  9.92775230e-01,  9.71548772e-01,
         9.31926675e-01,  8.70952635e-01,  7.84147337e-01],
       [ 1.24531829e-01,  2.14951720e-02, -1.24142269e-01,
        -2.88285785e-01, -4.36332137e-01, -5.38600278e-01,
        -5.79503157e-01, -5.52137571e-01, -4.50556205e-01,
        -2.72020914e-01, -3.08257107e-02,  2.33881288e-01,
         4.76396240e-01,  6.69624907e-01,  8.08474102e-01,
         9.00042790e-01,  9.55065954e-01,  9.83283570e-01,
         9.91629328e-01,  9.84084754e-01,  9.62320925e-01,
         9.26691302e-01,  8.77415997e-01,  8.15482847e-01],
       [ 2.08997618e-01,  1.24559020e-01,  8.48684407e-04,
        -1.46598137e-01, -2.88661918e-01, -3.91618296e-01,
        -4.29961569e-01, -3.89309376e-01, -2.63943288e-01,
        -6.30136416e-02,  1.78668276e-01,  4.12249396e-01,
         6.04758495e-01,  7.48714864e-01,  8.50152685e-01,
         9.17783980e-01,  9.59112226e-01,  9.79804775e-01,
         9.83901943e-01,  9.74114572e-01,  9.52212374e-01,
         9.19706766e-01,  8.78912089e-01,  8.33903997e-01],
       [ 2.82249691e-01,  2.18162184e-01,  1.22747194e-01,
         5.37550368e-03, -1.12692673e-01, -1.99604825e-01,
        -2.22963823e-01, -1.62177004e-01, -1.79584651e-02,
         1.81399471e-01,  3.89284568e-01,  5.68595908e-01,
         7.06857534e-01,  8.07907267e-01,  8.79716132e-01,
         9.28814854e-01,  9.59433518e-01,  9.74181247e-01,
         9.74926863e-01,  9.63345918e-01,  9.41247109e-01,
         9.11068122e-01,  8.76727946e-01,  8.44239721e-01],
       [ 3.46009504e-01,  3.03334542e-01,  2.40609727e-01,
         1.64792336e-01,  9.10650256e-02,  4.46918062e-02,
         5.47680721e-02,  1.36260477e-01,  2.74393229e-01,
         4.32734135e-01,  5.78349795e-01,  6.96327399e-01,
         7.86097123e-01,  8.52735284e-01,  9.01501863e-01,
         9.35893510e-01,  9.57589073e-01,  9.67107013e-01,
         9.64733890e-01,  9.51264330e-01,  9.28488288e-01,
         8.99692809e-01,  8.70252069e-01,  8.47561147e-01],
       [ 4.06955125e-01,  3.86836289e-01,  3.60008319e-01,
         3.33800629e-01,  3.19793639e-01,  3.32294319e-01,
         3.80910459e-01,  4.60529276e-01,  5.54085368e-01,
         6.45433976e-01,  7.25560042e-01,  7.91585217e-01,
         8.44113209e-01,  8.85113897e-01,  9.16480279e-01,
         9.39239758e-01,  9.53365969e-01,  9.58045905e-01,
         9.52421824e-01,  9.36509635e-01,  9.12084965e-01,
         8.83417478e-01,  8.57475919e-01,  8.42768229e-01],
       [ 4.75102487e-01,  4.79444876e-01,  4.91103049e-01,
         5.17028392e-01,  5.61580652e-01,  6.19364889e-01,
         6.75394533e-01,  7.20462603e-01,  7.57762648e-01,
         7.92301360e-01,  8.25331968e-01,  8.55937836e-01,
         8.83019438e-01,  9.05962858e-01,  9.24460078e-01,
         9.38025098e-01,  9.45636106e-01,  9.45638264e-01,
         9.36251692e-01,  9.16741704e-01,  8.89028586e-01,
         8.58882429e-01,  8.35359426e-01,  8.27878351e-01],
       [ 5.62693753e-01,  5.93592734e-01,  6.42845488e-01,
         7.09881932e-01,  7.82737342e-01,  8.39735853e-01,
         8.68496463e-01,  8.76464004e-01,  8.77560033e-01,
         8.80145097e-01,  8.86486243e-01,  8.95793855e-01,
         9.06385360e-01,  9.16670844e-01,  9.25375659e-01,
         9.31289596e-01,  9.32857010e-01,  9.27783629e-01,
         9.13322352e-01,  8.87929386e-01,  8.54220866e-01,
         8.20792210e-01,  7.99707058e-01,  8.00713493e-01],
       [ 6.75223956e-01,  7.28299137e-01,  7.98132045e-01,
         8.70828514e-01,  9.28100696e-01,  9.58357163e-01,
         9.63664076e-01,  9.54511170e-01,  9.41109289e-01,
         9.29563623e-01,  9.22166117e-01,  9.18823138e-01,
         9.18280235e-01,  9.18945445e-01,  9.19301773e-01,
         9.17852346e-01,  9.12687865e-01,  9.00755102e-01,
         8.77918913e-01,  8.41778780e-01,  7.97438172e-01,
         7.59412209e-01,  7.43766496e-01,  7.58426057e-01],
       [ 7.48028585e-01,  8.00967465e-01,  8.60639839e-01,
         9.17314355e-01,  9.62374525e-01,  9.89077372e-01,
         9.96239777e-01,  9.88737117e-01,  9.73767736e-01,
         9.57273913e-01,  9.42647501e-01,  9.30980153e-01,
         9.21800247e-01,  9.13829662e-01,  9.05516974e-01,
         8.95103386e-01,  8.80063037e-01,  8.55819040e-01,
         8.15680432e-01,  7.57286053e-01,  6.94667063e-01,
         6.54674360e-01,  6.55242773e-01,  6.95951505e-01],
       [ 5.88142228e-01,  6.56524283e-01,  7.39388262e-01,
         8.26540072e-01,  9.05382649e-01,  9.63084972e-01,
         9.93428420e-01,  9.99593348e-01,  9.90003898e-01,
         9.72940215e-01,  9.53944608e-01,  9.35599844e-01,
         9.18217361e-01,  9.00665492e-01,  8.80954002e-01,
         8.56210996e-01,  8.21553193e-01,  7.67628947e-01,
         6.82523479e-01,  5.74145986e-01,  4.89341942e-01,
         4.69017002e-01,  5.14459717e-01,  6.05048760e-01]]

V = [[-7.64071106e-01, -7.61939824e-01, -7.56999777e-01,

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6), dpi=300);

ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V, pivot='middle');
ax.set_aspect('equal');
```

Output:

[image]

I've tried the above. I expect single arrows as usual.

I don't know what additional details to add to get rid of the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't you ask for exactly that, repeating values 1 and 12?

```py
#(...)
X = [[ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
#(...)
Y = [[ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
         1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
         1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
#(...)
U = [[ 5.91106782e-01,  6.22366562e-01, 6.49723913e-01, (...)
     [ 5.77152607e-01,  5.82746773e-01,  5.76183972e-01, (...)
```

You even have a quadruple arrow at coordinate (1,1). Just pair X and Y, and see that X=1 Y=1 occurs 4 times! But values of U in those 4 occurences of X=1 Y=1 are all different. So those 4 arrows that starts for (1,1) are not exactly identical.

So does X=11 Y=1.

X=2 Y=1 occurs twice.

Etc.

You said "especially in the center". No, not really. It occurs on line Y=1, on column X=1, and, indeed on line Y=12 and column X=11 that both pass not far from the center.

Comment: X and Y were created with linspace, so I didn't really consider that. Must have that defined wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, so either you need to compute exactly the numbers (`linspace(1,22,22)` not `linspace(1,22,24)` because linspace boundaries are inclusive, and there are 22 integers from 1 to 22 included). Or to use np.arange(1,23), that would iterate values by steps of 1, so no need to overthink the number of steps you need. Or to accept non integers (you probably used a `.astype(np.int32)` or `dtype=np.int32`): `np.linspace(1,22,24)` without any `int` conversion would at least have displayed separated arrows, even if not exactly aligned with integer coordinates.

Comment: The problem came from 1) writing that block when I first started fighting with python, and 2) not wanting arrows around the border of the image I'm overlaying (indented 1 on all 4 sides). Just went back to the code and redid the linspace along with slicing the image data that yield U and V. No more weirdness. Much appreciated!